# How to force a hosted site to use asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting

My hosted asp.net site is erroring since it says it cant understand MasterPageFile in the Page directive. The error is reported by asp.net 1.1. My site is compiled to asp.net 2.0 and the hosting provider supports it.

I am not sure what I have done to upset the apple cart. I fear it's because I mistakenly deleted the empty cgi-bin and aspnet_client folders (since restored).

Any ideas how I can rectify this? Something in web.config perhaps?

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The 'MasterPageFile' attribute is not supported
>   by the 'page' directive.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="MasterPage.Master" %> Line 2:   Line 3:
>
> Source File: d:\webspace\xxxk\wwwroot\Default.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2504;
>   ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the site's application pool on the web server to be of 2.0 .NET version and not a 1.1 .NET application pool.

Comment: it's hosted i've no access to that. the control panel seems to know if its 1.1, 2.0 or php by what's in the folder

Comment: Sorry @jenson-button-event but I think Thanos is on the right track.  To my knowledge, I think this is an IIS setting, not an application setting.  You may have to give your hosting company a call and tell them to change it to 2.0...

Comment: correct - informed by support with the nice new knowledge they support up to v4.0